# Product information crawling

Tags: database, web-crawler, web-scraping

Suppose I have a big set of product names. How can I get as much information as possible about these products? For example their price, their category (e.g. electronics, home, toys)? Do you know any comprehensive product data set?

P.S. I am not allowed to scrape Amazon, Ebay, and Walmart.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no golden bullet web service for such data.

Most of the web services provide "best matched" results. For example, "iPhone 5" returns "iPhone 5 black 32G" and "iPhone 5 32g (black)". You could have a look at Amazon results: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=iPhone%205

The best way is to combine results from several sources. You could find a lot of APIs at: http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Shopping

I'm representative of http://aerse.com. We are building service, that address issues above. The main goal is to get product information using product name and product vendor.